# How to use Flow to enforce missing prop types

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

The flow definition

```
declare type ReactComponent<Props> = Class<React$Component<void, Props, *>> | (props: Props) => React$Element<*>;
```

The Title Component

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import styles from './Title.css';

type Props = {
    title: string,
    subTitle?: string,
};

function Title({ title, subTitle }: Props) {
    return (
        <section>
            <Helmet title={title} />
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            {subTitle && <h2>{subTitle}</h2>}
        </section>
    );
}

export default (withStyles(styles)(Title): ReactComponent<Props>);
```

So, now we have a Title Component that takes two props, both strings, with one of them being optional.

I then try to use the above component in another component.

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import styles from './TextureDetail.css';
import Title from '../../Title';

type Props = {
    postData: Map<*, *>,
    postTags: Array<*>,
};

function TextureDetail() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Title />
        </div>
    );
}

export default (withStyles(styles)(TextureDetail): ReactComponent<Props>);
```

In this instance I expect flow to complain that I am using the component Title without the required props, but it does not do so. How do I configure flow that it actually checks for required types.

Comment: have you checked this answer ? https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1279#issuecomment-172157104

Comment: @AmirHoseinian Unfortunately, that does not seem to have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the HOC (Higher Order Component) used to create `Title` from `isometric-style-loader` does not have associated flow types. Flow automatically converts untyped libraries to `any`, which is why you're not seeing any errors you'd normally expect to see from a component missing required props.

You can create bindings for its type using an example in the `flow-typed` repository for a similarly structured HOC, such as [react-css-modules](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-css-modules_v3.x.x/flow_v0.32.x-/react-css-modules_v3.x.x.js). You can also look around to see if someone else has released flow type definitions for this library, but I could not find any at the time of answering this question.